# How can a pointer refer to a different type?

Tags: c++

> (4.1/1) **If the object to which the lvalue refers is not an object of
>   type T and is not an object of a type derived from T**, or if the object
>   is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this conversion has
>   undefined behavior.

From this, I assume

```
struct B {
     int x; };

B *p;
*p; //undefined behavior
```

`*p` is a lvalue which refers to an uninitialized object. How can it refer to an object which is not the type of 'B' or its derived type? Am i misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
int n = 5;
double * p = reinterpret_cast<double*>(&n);

*p += 1.0; // undefined behaviour: p points to an int, not a double

++*reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);  // legal; pointer can be cast back-and-forth
```

Less easy:

```
union bogus { int * a; double * b; } B;
int n;
B.a = &n;
*B.b += 1.0; // undefined behaviour
```

Common C pitfall (produces *no diagnostic*!):

```
void do_a(void * p) { ++*reinterpret_cast<int*>(p); }
void do_b(void * p) { *reinterpret_cast<double*>(p) += 1.0; }

int main() { int n = 4; do_b(&n); /* eek */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

```
 int i;
 B *p;
 p = (B*)&i;
```

Done.

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it point to something that isn't of object T, or a derived type, is to type-pun with pointer casts:

```
struct A{ int x; };
struct B{ float x; };


A x;
B *p = (B*)&x;

*p;  //  Undefined behavior
```

In this example, the pointer `p` isn't pointing to something of type `B`. It points to something of type `A` which is incompatible.

Note that this example also violates strict-aliasing - which is also undefined behavior.